# Add search to custom query Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I build a custom query to count and sum some of the field and then use gridview to display data.

Here is my query:

```
$query2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'date', 
        'sum( IF(status = "Passed", 1, 0) ) AS passed', 
        'sum( IF(status = "Failed", 1, 0) ) AS failed', 
        'sum( IF(status = "On Hold", 1, 0) ) AS onhold', 
        'sum( IF(status <> "NULL", 1, 0) ) AS total'
    ])
    ->from('qa3d')->where(['week'=>$week])
    ->groupBy('date');

    $dataProvider2 = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query2,

    ]);
```

And my gridview:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            'heading' => 'Status Report by Analyst - Week to Date',
            ],
        'toolbar' =>  [
            '{toggleData}',
        ],
        'pjax' => true,
        'columns' => [

            'date',
            'passed',
            'failed',
            [
            'attribute' => 'onhold', 
            'label' => "On Hold",
            ],   
            'total',
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

I commented out the `filterModel` because it's not working. How can I build a search like Gii CRUD generator did for this custom query?

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to add your SearchModel or the `search()` function from the search model. One needs to know the model and field names to re-write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have. You must create search form that point to action of that page then u must decide how will you forward params. You can put it to search model or get it and pass to query you have. IT depends where is your query.

```
$searchModel = new SomeSearchModel();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

or like this and then access array elements.

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
```

In your case I supposed you will search for `$week = $post['week'];`